# PIG UDF error - Could resolve using imports

Tags: python, apache-pig, udf

Hello I am having an issue with running a pig script.

Here is my pig script:

```
REGISTER 'python_udf.py' USING jython AS myfuncs;
dataframe = LOAD 'udftest.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (x:int);
result1 = foreach dataframe generate myfuncs.testudf(x);
dump result1;
```

Here is my python script:

```
@schemaFunction("a:int")
def testudf(test):
a = test - 1
return a
```

The error I get is:

"Error during parsing. Could not resolve myfuncs.testudf using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [pig documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/udf.html#jython-udfs) it says under **Decorators and Schemas**

> **schemaFunction** - Defines delegate function and is not registered to Pig.

and

> **outputSchema** - Defines schema for a script UDF in a format that Pig understands and is able to parse

so try

```
@outputSchema('a:int')
```

as your decorator.